# AWS Lex: An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Lambda response elicited for an invalid slot name ​

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lex

Using a validation hook for AWS lex. If i try to elicit slot, lex fails with:

> An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Lambda response elicited for an invalid slot name ​

Below is my lex event and response from my lambda function. I have 2 slots, topping and crust. Topping was the first slot already given by client. Crust was the missing slot.

I have reviewed most of AWS documentation, stackoverflow and other tutorials but I can't seem to break past this..anyone have any idea?

LexEvent:

```
{
    "messageVersion": "1.0",
    "invocationSource": "DialogCodeHook",
    "userId": "cbzn2ql6dl59dro",
    "sessionAttributes": {},
    "outputDialogMode": "Text",
    "currentIntent": {
        "name": "Pizza",
        "slots": {
            "topping": "Chicken"
        },
        "confirmationStatus": "None"
    },
    "bot": {
        "name": "PizzaMaker",
        "alias": "$LATEST",
        "version": "$LATEST"
    }
}
```

Response from Lambda

```
{
    "sessionAttributes": {},
    "dialogAction": {
        "type": "ElicitSlot",
        "message": {
            "contentType": "PlainText",
            "content": "What type of crust do you want?"
        },
        "intentName": "Pizza",
        "slotToElicit": "​Curst",
        "slots": {
            "topping": "Chicken"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to add, I verified slot names are matching in lex and lambda (upper and lowercase too). The slot configuration is 1 prompt and 1 response card with options. No Slot Obfucation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried validating your Lambda response structure using [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) and noticed that there is an additional symbol included in the value for the `slotToElicit` key which is otherwise invisible. This would point to why Lex is unable to find the slot name.

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you for looking into it. The simplest things cause the most pain.

Answer (score 1):

The error "Lambda response elicited for an invalid slot name" is specifically saying that the slot you are trying to elicit with `"slotToElicit"` does not match a slot configured in your bot.

It may be this typo that is causing the problem: `"slotToElicit": "​Curst",`

Try `"slotToElicit": "​Crust",` or lowercase `"slotToElicit": "​crust",`

Comment: Thanks for the support..it was a lint issue :(.